# AHK Add Checkboxes dynamically

Tags: dynamic, autohotkey

I was wondering if anyone had any source for adding a Checkbox to a GUI dynamically? Basically i have a Loader that download AHK Scripts but i need to add a new Checkbox for every downloaded Script in my Gui that activates the Script if a condution is given like game xxx.exe is running

you can find the script Here: https://github.com/happymaj00r/HappyLoader

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to use a ListView for that. Using the `Checked` option you can have Checkboxes in every row. This way all the nasty scrollbar stuff is being handles for you automatically.

```
Gui, Add, ListView, r10 AltSubmit Checked v#HSList Hdr gListViewChecks, |Column
Gui, Add, Button, gButton, Add Row
Gui, Show,, Dynamically Add Checkboxes
Return

Button:
    LV_Add(Checked, "", "Another Row")
Return

ListViewChecks:
    If (A_GuiEvent == "I") {
        If (ErrorLevel == "C")
            ToolTip, % "Row " . A_EventInfo . " is checked."
        Else If (ErrorLevel == "c")
            ToolTip, % "Row " . A_EventInfo . " is unchecked."
    }
Return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

[image]